# Tracking Spring method calls without using Aspects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soa

For a few days, I am stuck at a (for me) quite challenging problem.

In my current project, we have a big SOA based architecture, our goal is to monitor and log all incoming requests, the invoked services, the invoked DAOs, and their result. For certain reasons we cant uses aspects, so our idea is to connect directly to the JavaVM and observe what's going on.

In our research, we found Byteman and Bytebuddy which both use the Java Machine Tool Interface to connect and inject code into the VM.

Looking closer at Byteman we discovered that we have to specify the Byteman-Operation for each operational class which in our case is simply impossible.

Would there be a better, more efficient way to log all incoming requests, the invoked services, the invoked DAOs, and their results? Should we write our own Agent which connects to the JMTI? What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to figure out a specific service method call can be overloaded. Wouldn't it be simplest and smarter to use APM?